# Dynamic variable substitution in PATH

Tags: bash, java, zsh, path, environment-variables

I want to run different versions of Java on the same machine (Linux Mint 17) with default to Java 7. So I put this into `/etc/environment`:

```
JAVA_HOME="/tools/java/java7"
JAVA7_HOME="/tools/java/java7"
JAVA8_HOME="/tools/java/java8"
```

And in `/etc/profile`:

```
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:...:${PATH}"
```

I expect `java -version` to be 8 if `JAVA_HOME` equals to `/tools/java/java8` and 7 if it is set to point to Java 7.

So, I run:

```
┌[madhead@madhead-mint:~/Projects/thymeleaf]
└─$ export JAVA_HOME=/tools/java/java8 && java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

And

```
┌[madhead@madhead-mint:~/Projects/thymeleaf]
└─! $ export JAVA_HOME=/tools/java/java7 && java -version
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

No matter what is `JAVA_HOME` `$PATH` looks like this:

```
┌[madhead@madhead-mint:~/Projects/thymeleaf]
└─$ echo $PATH
/home/madhead/bin:/usr/local/bin:/tools/java/java7/bin:...:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

And `export JAVA_HOME=/tools/java/java8 && which java` outputs `/tools/java/java7/bin/java` too.

So, it looks like real substitution appears when I log in. Can this behavior be changed? It would be great if I can solve this with env variables, and not with symlinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the substitution occurs when PATH is defined.  It is simple to get around that.  Define a `bash`/`zsh` function:

```
javaswitch() { [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]$ ]] && export  PATH=${PATH/java[0-9]/java$1}; }
```

Now, anytime that you want to switch java versions, run:

```
javaswitch 7
```

Or:

```
javaswitch 8
```

To make the definition of `javaswitch` permanent, place it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

#### How it works

- `[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]$ ]]`

  For protection against typos, this tests to make sure that the argument is a number.  If it isn't, then no change is made.

  If you are sure that you will only use versions 7 or 8, then use instead:

  ```
  [[ "$1" =~ ^[7-8]$ ]]
  ```
- `export  PATH=${PATH/java[0-9]/java$1}`

  This uses pattern substitution to update PATH to the new version number.